# compile help indices failed when title section has CJK characters

Tags: r, utf-8, cjk

I am making a R package of my own. However, I am having encoding problems with package help.

For the record, I need to write package help in Chinese. I write `.Rd` file with the following additional setup according to the document of writing R extention:

- add `\encoding{utf-8}` to the first line of each `.Rd` file
- save `.Rd` file as utf-8 encoded without BOM

And here are the results:
+ the CJK characters in the `description` section are correctly recognized in the help window of RStudio.
+ R compiler fails if there are CJK characters in the `title` section with the following message:

```
*** installing help indices
Error in gsub("&", "&amp;", x, fixed = TRUE) :
  invalid multibyte string at '<84> <74>op k €'
```

I believe international documents for R are necessary. Are there anyone has experience on this?

Comment: The R-devel mailing list. is where the most knowledgeable people with intersection knowledge about encoding and package construction hang out. They generally expect a greater amount of code. They may ask that you use command line invocation of the R CMD interpreter. The first sentence of the Internationalization section if the Writing R Extensions document says: "There are mechanisms to translate the R- and C-level error and warning messages. There are only available if R is compiled with NLS support (which is requested by configure option --enable-nls, the default)." And read the rest.

Comment: I mean writing .Rd documents in CJK characters, not message translation.

Comment: Well, offhand I would guess that getting your .Rd documents in CJK would require the same preparation but as I said ... the people who would really know are on r-devel. AND they will flame you if you have not read ALL of that section. AND post code. AND report error messages from attempting to run from the command line. (None of which you have done here so far.)

Comment: OK, I've fixed this problem by making several changes in the `tools` package. I believe most of them are 'bugs', or at least not handled properly.

Comment: You might make a useful contribution to your countrymen by reporting your changes to the R-devel mailing list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two fixes in install.r

- add `useBytes=T` for `gsub()` in `htmlize()`
- within `.writePkgIndices()`, add `encoding='UTF-8'` to `outcon`